# Matplotlib: how to add an arrow to a Path Patch?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a few path patches.

```
pp1 = mpatches.PathPatch(Path([(start_x, height), (middle_x, middle_y), (end_x, height)],[Path.MOVETO, Path.CURVE3, Path.CURVE3]),fc="none", transform=ax1.transData)
ax1.add_patch(pp1)
```

Which give me curved edges, as shown in the image below: 
[image]

How can I add arrows to the end/begin/middle of these curved edges?

I did a little bit of searching and figured other patches which contain arrows. I tried them but aligning them with my path patch turned out to be non-trivial. I wonder if there is an easier way to add an arrow to my edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think adding arrows in the middle of an arbitrary curve can be trivial, as shown by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35177675/draw-rounded-fancyarrowpatch-with-midpoint-arrow-in-matplotlib#answer-36223973).

However, you can use [`patches.FancyArrowPatch`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch.html) to have arrow head(s) at both/either ends of a curve:

```
import matplotlib.path as mpath
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Path = mpath.Path

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fap1 = mpatches.FancyArrowPatch(path=Path([(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0)],
                                         [Path.MOVETO, Path.CURVE3, Path.CURVE3]),
                                arrowstyle="<|-|>,head_length=10,head_width=10")
ax.add_patch(fap1)
ax.set_xlim(-1, 2)
ax.set_ylim(-1, 2)

plt.show()
```

[image]